# How to use the {n} syntax of regex with CMake

Tags: regex, cmake, repeat

I have this string "2017-03-05-02-10-10_78205" and I want to match it with this pattern `[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){5}_[0-9]+` but it doesn't work on CMake. See this example in CMake :

```
set(stuff "2017-03-05-02-10-10_78205")
if( "${stuff}" MATCHES "[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){5}_[0-9]+")
  message("Hello")
endif()
```

CMake doesn't seem to support the syntax `{n}`. Obviously, I solved my problem with that pattern `[0-9-]+_[0-9]+`

Nevertheless, I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong with the syntax `{n}`. Is it supported by CMake ? If not, how to define a specific number of repetition with CMake ?

I'm using an old CMake version (2.8.11.2).

Comment: You can just use `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](-[0-9][0-9])(-[0-9][0-9])(-[0-9][0-9])(-[0-9][0-9])(-[0-9][0-9])_[0-9]+` as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get around this problem by using shell commands and `execute_process`.
For instance, with `echo` and `grep` on linux :

```
set(stuff "2017-03-05-02-10-10_78205")
set(regexp "[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){5}_[0-9]+")
execute_process( COMMAND echo "${stuff}"
                 COMMAND grep -E -o "${regexp}"
                 OUTPUT_VARIABLE thing )
if(thing)
  message("Hello")
endif()
```

But we loose the cross-platform aspect of CMake.

Answer (score 4):

According to [CMake's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/string.html), it does not support the `{n}` syntax. Taken from that page:

```
The following characters have special meaning in regular expressions:
^         Matches at beginning of input  
$         Matches at end of input  
.         Matches any single character  
[ ]       Matches any character(s) inside the brackets  
[^ ]      Matches any character(s) not inside the brackets
-         Inside brackets, specifies an inclusive range between
          characters on either side e.g. [a-f] is [abcdef]
          To match a literal - using brackets, make it the first
          or the last character e.g. [+*/-] matches basic
          mathematical operators.
*         Matches preceding pattern zero or more times
+         Matches preceding pattern one or more times 

?         Matches preceding pattern zero or once only   
|         Matches a pattern on either side of the |  
()        Saves a matched subexpression, which can be referenced
          in the REGEX REPLACE operation. Additionally it is saved
          by all regular expression-related commands, including
          e.g. if( MATCHES ), in the variables CMAKE_MATCH_(0..9).
```

It does not seem to be a way to define a specific number of repetitions, rather than copying the expression, e.g.:

```
[0-9]{5}
```

would become

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: Yes I know that but we loose the compactness of regular expression :(

Answer (score 1):

CMake doesn't support the `{n}` format, so repeating the pattern `n` times is required. This can become quite unwieldy, but you can easily generate the regex-pattern itself using `string(REPEAT)`:

```
set(rx_num "[0-9]")
string(REPEAT "${rx_num}" 2 rx_num2)
string(REPEAT "${rx_num}" 4 rx_num4)
string(REPEAT "-${rx_num2}" 5 rx_dnum2x5)
set(rx_date "${rx_num4}${rx_dnum2x5}_${rx_num}+")

set(stuff "2017-03-05-02-10-10_78205")
message("${rx_date}")
if( "${stuff}" MATCHES "${rx_date}")
  message("Hello")
endif()
```

output:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_[0-9]+
Hello
```

This becomes more useful as the repetition-count and expression-complexity increase. The above example is (intentionally) excessive and arguably uglier than just the raw regex with repeats.