# Reading xml file using CMake using string(REGEX MATCH)

Tags: regex, xml, cmake

I am trying to extract some data from an XML file for build purposes using CMake. XML file is eclipse .cproject file, and I want to extract preprocessor macros defined in it. Data I want to extract is structured as below.

```
<option (...) name="Defined symbols (-D)" (...)><listOptionValue (...) value="(Interesting data)" /><more tags listOptionValue with defined symbols></option>
```

I tried to use `string(REGEX MATCH ...)` to extract interesting data, but I failed, because I could not find a way to force CMake to match `.*` in a non-greedy way.

Is there a way to read XML files using CMake in more elegant way? Or at least how to force CMake `string(REGEX MATCH ...)` to match in non-greedy way?

Comment: `Or at least how to force CMake  'string(REGEX MATCH ...)' to match in non-greedy way?` - According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35845992/3440745), there is no way for CMake to match in non-greedy-way.